# How to use if condition in a tool bar in java script

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new in react native and java script. I would like to check, when the item in my tool bar is equal to 'A', (when some body selects A) then the touchable property becomes false. I wrote it in this way:

```
init: function( pThis ) {
  toolbarActiveItem:  'test',
        this.state = {
        toolbar: [
                {
                  id: 5,
                  name: 'test',
                  description: I18n.t('test'), 
                  if(this.item=='A'){
                     isTouchable: false,
                    }
                  else {
                        isTouchable: true,
                       }
                  onOpen: (item) => { this.onToolbarOpen(pThis,item) },
                  },
               ],
        };

        this.onToolbarOpen(pThis);
    },
```

However I got the error in syntax. I should mention that, the code is working without the if condition. Can you help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put an `if` statement in the middle of an object literal.

You could construct it in two stages:

```
var obj = {};
if (foo) {
    obj.bar = 1;
} else {
    obj.bar = 2;
}
// then pass `obj` somewhere
```

You could use a ternary operator:

```
isTouchable: ( this.item=='A' ? true : false ),
```

… but since an equality comparison gives you a boolean, it would be simplest to just assign that:

```
isTouchable: ( this.item == 'A' )
```

Comment: Very nice answer! thank you so much. just one more question, what if I have 2 conditions. For example,  what if I need to check A and B for items at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

the `toolbar` element is an object, in which you can't use an if statement. You will have to use a variable declared earlier that you can fill in later:

```
init: function( pThis ) {
var touchable;
if(this.item=='A'){
    touchable = false,
}
else {
    touchable = true,
}
toolbarActiveItem:  'test',
    this.state = {
    toolbar: [
            {
              id: 5,
              name: 'test',
              description: I18n.t('test'), 
              isTouchable: touchable,
              onOpen: (item) => { this.onToolbarOpen(pThis,item) },
              },
           ],
    };

    this.onToolbarOpen(pThis);
},
```